# how to get the result of cart in the model in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My cart have two roomname.I loop the cart to get all value of roomname and  want  data of the both two roomname in the view.

My Model

```
public function getextrabedinfo(){


    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as  $cart) {

        $roomname = $cart['roomname']; 

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM roomcalendar where roomname='$roomname' ");

        return $query->result();

    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question if you want to send data from model to view then try your code in this way..

```
 public function getextrabedinfo(){

$alldata = array();
    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as  $cart) {

        $roomname = $cart['roomname']; 

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM roomcalendar where roomname='$roomname' ");

        $alldata[] = $query->result();

    }   
return $alldata ;

}
```

Try this .. Hope it will work.

Comment: thanks it work. can you tell me more how to loop this two data in the view page. i use this . foreach ($extrabedinfo as $key =>$extrabed) {
    print_r($extrabed);  
   }

Comment: You welocme ..Now in view, $extrabedinfo is a simple object  array . you can retrieve  data in view by simple foreah loop e.g. .... foreach($extrabedinfo as $ex){ echo $ex->index; print_r($ex);  } Just use as simple code ..

Comment: what is echo $ex->index; ? i can't find index value.

Comment: Dear I have just dummy write it $ex->index... you can use field name of table .. E.g. $ex->id, $ex->bed , $ex->room etc